# how to edit git commit without modify the struct of the history of the commit

Tags: git, commit

suppose I have such a commit log

```
A -> B -> C(HEAD)
```

Now I checkout A and edit file, I want to keep editing and update it to A and still keep B and C untouched, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it right, you need to create another branch from A. Let's name it D.

```
git checkout A
git branch D
```

And then you can checkout to this branch.

```
git checkout D
```

So, you will have two different flows, B and C will stay untouched.

[image]

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer to include the relevant information directly.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Updated

Answer (score 2):

Checkout your repository to A.

```
$ git checkout A
```

Then create a branch from it.

```
$ git checkout -b feature-branch
```

Make the changes you want. `B` and `C` will be untouched. When you are ready to incorporate the changes into `master` (or whatever is the main branch), simply go to the branch

```
$ git checkout master
```

and merge the other branch

```
$ git merge feature-branch
```